# How to put ContextMenu into Window.Resources

Tags: wpf, xaml

As you can see I am able to put **Height** property and **Foreground** property to the Window.Resources

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="StackOverFlow">
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Background="Blue"/>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

How can I put `<ContextMenu Background="Blue"/>` to the Window.Resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the context menu into separate resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu" Background="Blue"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="StackOverFlow"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: **Dear Pavel Anikhouski**, _Could you please tell me why did you put the following code?_  `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"`

Comment: It means that your style in based on default `TextBox` style. You can look through [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon?view=netframework-4.8) to get some examples

Comment: I deleted that line and the code still works. So is it really necessary?

Comment: It's necessary in more complicated scenarios and style customizations